# Why the word "common ground" as noun does not contain or unnecessary to have a hyphen?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Why the word "common ground" as noun does not contain or unnecessary to have a hyphen? Is this compound term correct?

Comment: I would hyphenate it if it is used as an adjective for something else.  *The common-ground rule*

Answer (score 2):

Compounds don't always have to be hyphenated, for example: *science fiction*, *nobel prize*, *peer pressure*.

On the other hand, some compounds are so well used that over time they have become a single word: *thereafter*, *bedroom*, *forever*.

As far as I am aware, there's no hard and fast rule about it, and in fact there can even be different preferences between American English and British English.

[Here's the wikipedia article about compounds for reference.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_compound#Hyphenated_compound_modifiers)

Answer (score 0):

A second reason not to hyphenate this compound (and other compound nouns generally) is that it implies a change in stress from the second term in the compound to the first. An example would be the difference between a 'common place' (as in, a place everyone goes to) and 'common-place' (a usual thing or event).

In the case of common-ground, the hyphenation creates a tenuous word - maybe it would imply something like a parade-ground, but isn't something I've heard of.